# Make column height match height of responsive carousel

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

On my website, I have a responsive carousel that takes up 75% of the width and a news column on the right that takes up the other 25%. 
I want the height of the news column to match the height of the carousel whenever the window is resized, and I've done so successfully with the following jQuery:

```
function equalizeHeights() {
    var height = $('#carousel').height();
    $('#news').css('height', height + 'px');
};

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();

    var height = $('#carousel').height();
    $('#news').css('height', height + 'px');

    equalizeHeights();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        equalizeHeights();
    });
});
```

However, since it's grabbing the height of the carousel first and then applying it to the section, there's a visible lag when you resize the window and I was wondering what a better way to do this would be so that both resize together.

Comment: Use CSS, that's what it was made for.

Comment: Sorry? If I'm missing an obvious solution, it'd still be nice to have a little guidance.

Comment: Have you got some HTML/CSS or a fiddle to show? Easier to test around and find a solution with